# AttributeError: 'FastTextKeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'vocab'

Tags: nlp, gensim, fasttext

I'm trying to load and use some pre-trained fasttext embeddings (that were trained by me and stored in .kv). In the same directory I have stored the `"vectors_1920_fullsample.kv.vectors_vocab.npy"` file. When Does someone know what is going on?

This doesn't give any error:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
stemmer = SnowballStemmer("english")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import os
import joblib
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
import random
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
import pandas as pd


model = KeyedVectors.load(wd_model + '/vectors_1920_fullsample.kv', mmap='r')

words = ['immigrant','immigrants','migrant','migrants','foreign','foreigner','foreigners','alien','aliens','expatriate','expatriates','emigrant','emigrants','nonnative','nonnatives','stranger','strangers']
```

But then when I do this I get the error below:

```
words = pd.DataFrame([np.array(model[word]) for word in words])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-6.3.0/python/3.7.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 353, in __getitem__
    return self.get_vector(entities)
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-6.3.0/python/3.7.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 471, in get_vector
    return self.word_vec(word)
  File "/cluster/apps/nss/gcc-6.3.0/python/3.7.4/x86_64/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py", line 2124, in word_vec
    if word in self.vocab:
AttributeError: 'FastTextKeyedVectors' object has no attribute 'vocab'
```

Comment: Where did the pre-trained embeddings come from? From the class name (`FastTextKeyedVectors`), it look like you're using the `gensim` library - what version are you using? Can you edit your question to show the full multiline error message, with traceback info (showing involved code/line-numbers)?

Comment: hey @gojomo, thanks for your answer. I updated the question so it is more complete. I am using python 3.7.4, as you can see above. Now the model is loading (as in it doesn't give any errors) but as soon as I try to access it, it gives the error above.

Comment: How specifically were the pre-trained embeddings – the file(s) beginning `vectors_1920_fullsample.kv` – created & saved? For example, which version of `Gensim` was used when/where they were created & saved? What code was used to save which part of the trained model? (A whole `FastText` instance or just some part of it?) And which version of `Gensim` (not Python) are you using now? (Are you sure you're using the latest version? Recent versions *don't* have a line 2124 in `keyedvectors.py` about FastText vectors!)

Comment: @gojomo to answer your questions:
- i checked and was using gensim 4.0.1 to train the vectors and now i set gensim to that version (`pip install gensim==4.0.1 --user`) but it still doesn't work. for fasttext i used this: `model = FastText(vector_size=256, window=8, min_count=10, epochs=1, workers=workers)`, then built the vocab, then trained the model, and then saved it like this: `from gensim.models import KeyedVectors`
`fasttext_allyears = model.wv`
`fasttext_allyears.save('vectors_1920_fullsample.kv')`

Comment: What code was used to save which part of the trained model? (It may be easier to show your code by editing your question than with a discussion-reply.) As far as I can tell, it would be impossible for `gensim-4.0.1` to generate the traceback error stack in your question. So when you say "it still doesn't work", are you sure it's failing in the exact same way? Can you extend your question to fully describe exactly what training-saving-loading-error cycle you are now getting, when using the same version of Gensim at every step? (Also: you might as well use latest Gensim 4.1+.)